# What's the correct way to diagram chained member functions in a UML 2 Sequence Diagram?

Tags: uml, sequence-diagram

Typically the calls on a Sequence Diagram are of the form

```
function(parameters);
```

How do I diagram chained function calls like this?:

```
stdList.front().pack(parameters);
```

front() returns an object of a different class so this is sort of like writing...

```
StdList stdList;
SomeClass a& = stdList.front();
a.pack(parameters);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like a self-call.  Have the method call loop back to the instance that called it.